# Laravel 4 pivot table with 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationships

I have those 4 models:

```
Book (table: books)
    - id
    - name
    - timestamps

Page (table: pages, belongs to many books)
    - id
    - name
    - timestamps

Word (table: word, belongs to many pages of many books)
    - id
    - name
    - timestamps

BookPageWord (Pivot table: book_page_word)
    - id
    - book_id
    - page_id
    - word_id
    - timestamps
```

The result i expect..

```
Book 1 -> Page 1 -> Word 1, Word 2
          Page 2 -> Word 2, Word 1, Word 3

Book 2 -> Page 1 -> Word 5, Word 1, Word 3, etc..
          Page 2 -> Word 2, Word 1, etc.
          Page 3 -> Word 5, Word 5, etc.
```

then i call

```
$book = Book::with('pages','pages.words')->find(1);
```

Until the second 'page' relationship works well, fails on third 'word' giving me words from other books.

Anyone know how to use pivot table with 3 FK?

Comment: Show your relations and how exactly you want to use that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, but why not use something like this: `Book has many pages`, `Page has many words, belongs to book`, `Word belongs to many page`